# Detaching a subdirectory into a new repo but keeping it as a subfolder

Tags: git

I have been looking a git filter branch and subtrees to detach a sub folder, that I would like to take from one repo into another. However I would like to retain the sub folder in the new repo, rather the contents of the sub folder being root.

So that:

```
repo/
|-- sub1/
|-- sub2/
|-- sub3/
```

Becomes:

```
repo2/
|-- sub2/
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Is there a reason not to simply clone the repo and then remove the other sub-directories?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter ./sub2
git push repo2 HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep `sub2` and remove everything else, this should do it:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'for i in * .*; do test "$i" = . -o "$i" = .. -o "$i" = sub2 && continue; rm -fr "$i"; done' --prune-empty
```

That is,
the command inside `--tree-filter` will iterate over the directory contents and remove everything except `.`, `..` and `sub2`, and all the commits that become empty by doing this.

Another variant of the same thing that's somewhat simpler but won't handle paths with embedded newlines:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git ls-files | grep -v ^sub2/ | xargs rm -fr' -f --prune-empty
```